# npm is installing dependencies in a weird recursive way

Tags: npm

I used `npm install --dev` to install the dependencies listed in a `package.json` file and it seems that rather than installing all the packages in a flat structure, it is installing the dependencies of each module inside the module's directory.

I had to cancel it because it was taking a lot, because many dependencies should have been already satisfied but it had to re-download them in a different nested directory (and I hope that there are not loops and it would have eventually finished)...

Using the tree command this is an example of what I am getting:

```
├── grunt-cli
│   └── node_modules
│       ├── findup-sync
│       │   └── node_modules
│       │       ├── glob
│       │       │   └── node_modules
│       │       │       ├── minimatch
│       │       │       │   └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       ├── lru-cache
│       │       │       │       │   └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       │       └── weak
│       │       │       │       │           └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       │               └── mocha
│       │       │       │       │                   └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       │                       ├── coffee-script
│       │       │       │       │                       │   └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       │                       │       └── jison
│       │       │       │       │                       │           └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       │                       │               └── browserify
│       │       │       │       │                       │                   └── node_modules
│       │       │       │       │                       │                       ├── browser-resolve
│       │       │       │       │                       │                       │   └── example
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't worry, that's actually the way Npm was designed.  You may even see the same module installed many times (though typically with different versions).

The idea is that each module installed under node_modules is a somewhat self-contained installation of that module with its dependencies and the necessary versions  -- it doesn't depend on modules installed globally.

If you are worried about inefficiency of modules being installed multiple times, the experimental [npm dedupe](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html).

Comment: But why? I am struggling to find a valid argument for this approach when searching around the web. What is wrong with installing them globally or using a flat structure? What problems does this actually solve? Seems like you could install everything in a flat structure and just include versions in the directory names to avoid conflicts. Current implementation seems very inefficient.

Comment: Check this article out @Danny: http://dontkry.com/posts/code/modules-the-right-way.html

Comment: THANKS @jackyalcine for that link. I was very frustrated with NPM. But that article clears it all up, and gives me some great tools to manage the directory depth problem. (yes, I'm using windoz, sadly).

Comment: Glad that helps @JohnHenckel!

Answer (score 2):

dedupe is helpful, as Jonathan Warden says. However, [try npm3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm3). For a simple package such as gulp-jscs the install of npm3 was 20% fewer files, 5% less disk space.  And tree depth went from 22 to 5.  However npm3 was 2x slower for me.