# Npm install module provide a lot of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I use the npm install 6 month ago and install module it create new **one** folder under the node_modules, the folder with all files for this module, but now when I use it create multifile files for one module, how can I install a module to specific folder as before ?
I use webStrorm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install behaving differently between computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601989/npm-install-behaving-differently-between-computers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   with no nesting.

Yes, in npm 3 your dependencies will be installed maximally flat, so it's all about npm versions.

Try running `npm -v` to make sure of that.

Here's [an article](http://dailyjs.com/2015/06/26/npm-3/) about that.

Comment: Ok thanks 1+ , there is a way somehow to tell the npm to explicit install it to specific folder?

Comment: @JhonD here's some github discussion about that https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9809 . Probably youll need to go for some npm fork.