# npm install generate more folders than needed

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm

I've been using `ember` for a while and when I wanted to install the node dependencies of a project, I just needed to use `npm install` to create the folder `node_modules` with all the dependencies (as it's described in http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/).

Since I was using an old version of `node` I unisntalled `node` and `npm` and installed `nvm` with the versions `node v5.0.0` and `npm v3.3.6`but now, when I try to use `npm install` to install the dependencies of a project as I used to do before, instead of the dependencies of the `package.json` file, I get many, many more from things I'm not sure where they come (I think they are dependencies that `npm` handles by itself in a globally way but now it's adding them to my project locally, but I'm not sure).

Why am I getting all those unknown (for me) dependencies?

Notice that, when I run `ember new` it generates the correct dependencies in `node_modules` but if I delete this folder and run `npm install` happens the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Install behaving differently between computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601989/npm-install-behaving-differently-between-computers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the changes introduced by npm v3.0:

> Your dependencies will now be installed flat - by default. If
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and their
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   without nesting. Nesting will only occur when two or more modules have
>   conflicting dependencies.

Read more at http://www.felixrieseberg.com/npm-v3-is-out-and-its-a-really-big-deal-for-windows/

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that there was a problem with my installation of node and npm. Isn't it possible to use them globally instead of locally so in the project will be the ones related to the `package.json`?

Comment: The packages you can see in your `node_modules` subfolder are still the local dependencies which you specified in your `package.json`, the only difference is that now your dependencies' dependencies are in that folder too, while before they were always nested in each dependency folder :)